# OpenGL - have object follow mouse

Tags: c++, opengl, computational-geometry, glm-math

I want to have an object follow around my mouse on the screen in OpenGL. (I am also using GLEW, GLFW, and GLM). The best idea I've come up with is:

Get the coordinates within the window with glfwGetCursorPos.

The window was created with

```
window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Test", NULL, NULL);
```

and the code to get coordinates is

```
double xpos, ypos;
glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
```

Next, I use GLM unproject, to get the coordinates in "object space"

```
glm::vec4 viewport = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f);
glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(xpos, ypos, 0.0f);
glm::vec3 un = glm::unProject(pos, View*Model, Projection, viewport);
```

There are two potential problems I can already see. The viewport is fine, as the initial x,y, coordinates of the lower left are indeed 0,0, and it's indeed a 1024*768 window. However, the position vector I create doesn't seem right. The Z coordinate should probably not be zero. However, glfwGetCursorPos returns 2D coordinates, and I don't know how to go from there to the 3D window coordinates, especially since I am not sure what the 3rd dimension of the window coordinates even means (since computer screens are 2D). Then, I am not sure if I am using unproject correctly. Assume the View, Model, Projection matrices are all OK. If I passed in the correct position vector in Window coordinates, does the unproject call give me the coordinates in Object coordinates? I think it does, but the documentation is not clear.

Finally, to each vertex of the object I want to follow the mouse around, I just increment the x coordinate by un[0], the y coordinate by -un[1], and the z coordinate by un[2]. However, since my position vector that is being unprojected is likely wrong, this is not giving good results; the object does move as my mouse moves, but it is offset quite a bit (i.e. moving the mouse a lot doesn't move the object that much, and the z coordinate is very large). I actually found that the z coordinate un[2] is always the same value no matter where my mouse is, possibly because the position vector I pass into unproject always has a value of 0.0 for z. However, varying the last coordinate in the position vector doesn't fix the fact that the object moves much slower than the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main issue is actually the z coordinate. When you consider a point on the screen, this will not just specify a point in object space, but a *straight line*. When you use a persepctive projection, you can draw a line from the eye position to any object space point, and every point on such a line will be projected to the same screen-space point.

So what you get when you unproject with z=0 is actually the point on the near plane. Now it will depend on how far your object is away from the camera, as sketched here in top view.

[image: sketch of unprojecting with a frustum]

What you get is point A in coordinates relative to the object space origin. You could get point B back if you just read the Z value from the pixel under the mouse curser back from the depth buffer.

However, I think that neither point A or B are really helping you. You need some further constraint. For example, you could specify that the distance of the object is not changed, and the pixel the mouse is pointing at shall be the point where the object center (or any other reference point in object space) should appear. Then, you could just compute the point on the ray you have to move the point to. But it is not really clear what kind of movement you actually want to implement.

As a side note: Manually adjusting the vertex coordinates is not a good idea. The GPU can do this far better. You should just manipulate the model matrix to move the object around. And it would be useful in such a scheme not to project the point or ray into the object space, but into world space, and use that to update the model matrix of the object.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this "further constraint" please. I have a really hard time implementing this and instead do a PosNew - PosOld * SomeMult * TransformToMove. This of course gives me the offset that OP talks about. What I really want is the 1:1 connection like moving objects in a 3d editor like maya.

Comment: @waaitt: Well, the mouse coords are just 2D, you have to define some rule for using that for 3D movements. Often, such movements are constrained by moving the object around on a plane.

Comment: What I meant to say is that I have unprojected or inverse matrix coords from the mouse pos. So my equation is for example TranslateX += (unProjectMouseX_new.x - unProjectMouseX_old.x) * someMult. Now, I want to move for example a 3d manipulator around which moves the object its attached to, like the XYZ translate manipulator in maya.

Comment: @derhass Actually, I believe it is also projecting onto the plane z = 0 in object space, because I have features to zoom / move around the camera and the object is coplanar with the other things in the object z = 0 plane.

Comment: @user2258552: If it were projection onto object space z=0, you would directly see that, and not getting some "very large" z coordinate.

Comment: Sorry - I fixed the large z - coordinate part. But the x and y coordinates are now wrong.

Anyway, I will try manipulating the model matrix as you said.